# Преобразование системы координат для вращения камеры

Tags: java, android, математика, 3d, координаты

Опишу задачу и проблему. Собственно задача у меня поворачивать камеру в 3D мире вверх, вниз, влево и вправо.

Для этого соответственно мне нужно перевести систему координат из декартовой в сферическую, сделать необходимые расчеты и перевести обратно из сферической в декартовую. Сделать это очень просто:

```
// Получаю вектор куда смотрит камера
Vec3 localLookCoord = Vec3.vec3MinusVec3(pos1, look1);

float r, y, o; // Определители точки куда смотрит камера в сферической системе координат

// Перевожу из декартовой системы координат в сферическую
r =  (float) Math.sqrt(localLookCoord.x*localLookCoord.x + localLookCoord.y*localLookCoord.y+ localLookCoord.z*localLookCoord.z  );
y =  (float) Math.atan(localLookCoord.z / localLookCoord.x);
o =  (float)Math.acos(localLookCoord.y / r);

// Уменьшаю угол тетта, причем нужно следить что бы небыл меньше нуля
if (o > 0.0f) o -= 0.01f; else o = 0.0f;

// Перевожу из сферической системы координат в декартовою
localLookCoord.x = (float) (r* Math.sin(o) * Math.cos(y));
localLookCoord.y = (float) (r* Math.cos(o));
localLookCoord.z = (float) (r* Math.sin(o) * Math.sin(y));

// Устанавливаю координаты направления взгляда камеры
look1.setVec3(localLookCoord);
```

И вот тут начинается проблема: когда угол тетта приближается к нулю, камера дергается как парализованная, из-за того что при переводе из `double` во `float` и назад, получаются разные значения... И я не знаю как решить эту проблему, я хочу чтобы был `Math` класс для `float`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем. Давайте разберемся, если я использую матрицу вращения для вращения камеры вокруг своей оси, тогда возникает вопрос, а как же мне найти току куда смотрит камера? Вытащить ее из матрицы? Если это возможно то подскажите как? Я создал отдельный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448317/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B), кто сможет ответе. Как из матрицы вращения вытащить точку направления камеры?

Но так как я вижу только один вариант, это преобразование декартовой системы координат в сферическую, выполнения вращения именно точки направления, а потом обратно из сферической в декартову. И у меня получилось! Я просто забыл в конце прибавить координаты точки, что бы она встала на прежнее место:

```
    // Получаю вектор куда смотрит камера
    Vec3 localLookCoord =  Vec3.vec3MinusVec3(pos1, look1);

     // Определители точки куда смотрит камера в сферической системе координат
    double r, y, o;
    // Перевожу из декартовой системы координат в сферическую
    r =  (float) Math.sqrt(localLookCoord.x*localLookCoord.x + localLookCoord.y*localLookCoord.y+ localLookCoord.z*localLookCoord.z  );
    y =  (float) Math.atan(localLookCoord.z / localLookCoord.x);
    o =  (float) Math.acos(localLookCoord.y / r);

    // Уменьшаю угол тетта, причем нужно следить что бы небыл меньше нуля
    if (o <=0.1f) o = 0.1f; else  o -= 0.01f;

    // Перевожу из сферической системы координат в декартовою
    localLookCoord.x = (float) (r* Math.sin(o) * Math.cos(y));
    localLookCoord.y = (float) (r* Math.cos(o));
    localLookCoord.z = (float) (r* Math.sin(o) * Math.sin(y));

    // Устанавливаю координаты направления взгляда камеры
    look1= Vec3.vec3SummVec3(pos1, localLookCoord);
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете попытаться воспользоваться [`Math.atan2`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2(double,%20double)):

```
y =  (float) Math.atan2(localLookCoord.z, localLookCoord.x);
```

Тогда у вас может быть меньше проблем и граничных случаев. Но вообще как вы делаете - так никто по факту не делает. Ни один трёхмерный движок не переводит декартовы координаты в сферические. Вместо этого декартов вектор умножается на матрицу вращения, которая однозначно высчитывается по оси вращения и углу поворота. Если у вас угол фиксированный (скажем, 0.01 радиан), матрицу можно вообще забить константой в программу. Скажем, для вращения вокруг оси Z нужна матрица вроде такой:

```
double[][] rotMatrix = {{Math.cos(0.01), Math.sin(0.01), 0}, 
                        {-Math.sin(0.01), Math.cos(0.01), 0},
                        {0, 0, 1}};
```

Реализуйте умножение вектора на матрицу, и будет вам счастье. Заметьте, что никакой тригонометрии вообще не нужно будет при конкретных вращениях. И никаких граничных случаев. Вообще почитайте теорию, как работает 3D-графика. Там матрицы и четырёхмерные координаты рулят, с ними всё очень просто.

Что касается `double` и `float`, проще вести все расчёты в `double`, а про тип `float` забыть. Он может пригодиться, в редких случаях, если у вас где-то есть реальные проблемы с производительностью, которые не решаются другими способами.

Comment: В конце концов я и делаю подобное преобразование в матрицу Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix,0, cameraMove.getX() ,cameraMove.getY(),cameraMove.getZ(),    cameraMove.getLookX() ,cameraMove.getLookY(),cameraMove.getLookZ() ,   0, 1, 0); Просто произвольную точку с помощью матриц можно поворачивать по конкретной оси, но не вокруг произвольной.

Comment: @CJ1, почему вы так решили? Вот [для произвольной оси матрица](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Матрица_поворота#.D0.9C.D0.B0.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.86.D0.B0_.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.82.D0.B0_.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.BA.D1.80.D1.83.D0.B3_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B9_.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.B8).

Comment: Вы полностью правы. Это все я конечно знаю. Я просто хотел добиться такого эффекта, что будет класс камеры, который будет возвращать не матрицу вида, а будет возвращать именно Vec3 позицию камеры и Vec3 точку направления камеры. Именно по этому я хотел сделать с переводом координат, так я задумал свой класс, но вот столкнулся с проблемой, по всей видимости придется делать через матрицы.

Comment: @CJ1 Вы можете точно так же производить все расчеты координат в своем классе через матрицы, а возвращать координаты и направления. Какая сложность в этот класс передать координаты, преобразовать через матрицу и вернуть преобразованные координаты ..

Comment: @pavlofff Теперь уж я так и сделаю. Сложность была в изначальной идеи преобразовывать точки, но теперь я понимаю что лучше работать с матрицами.

Comment: @pavlofff Оказывается не так просто взять вектор направления из камеры, если можете помогите: [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448317/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B)