# Вернуть вектор направления камеры

Tags: android, opengl, матрицы

Значит есть матрица вида, из нее нужно взять направления камеры.
Изначально устанавливаем матрицу вида один раз:

```
matrixView = new float[16];
Matrix.setIdentityM(matrixView, 0);
pos1.x=-20;
pos1.y=0;
pos1.z=10;
look1.x=0;
look1.y=0
look1.z=30;
Matrix.setLookAtM(matrixView,0, pos1.x ,pos1.y,pos1.z, look1.x,look1.y,look1.z ,   0, 1, 0);
```

Далее, идет цикл:

```
        Тут мы Рисуем......

        // Добавляю к вектору позиции нормализированный вектор направления взгляда
        Vec3 lengthPosLook = Vec3.vec3MinusVec3(pos1, look1);
        Vec3 normalSpeed = Vec3.vec3Normal(lengthPosLook);

        pos1 = Vec3.vec3SummVec3(pos1, normalSpeed);
        look1 = Vec3.vec3SummVec3(look1, normalSpeed);
        Matrix.setLookAtM(matrixView,0, pos1.x ,pos1.y,pos1.z, look1.x,look1.y,look1.z ,   0, 1, 0);

        Тут матрицу крутим как хотим вокруг своей оси, поэтому вектор look1 сбит, и значения ег оне актуальны.

        Теперь пытаюсь вытащить look1
        float invert[] = new float[16];
        float k = 5;
        Matrix.invertM(invert, 0, matrixView, 0);
        pos1.x = invert[12]; 
        pos1.y = invert[13]; 
        pos1.z = invert[14];
        look1.x = -((pos1.x+invert[8])*k); 
        look1.y = -((pos1.y+invert[9])*k) ; 
        look1.z = -((pos1.z+invert[10])*k);
```

И к сожалению как не крути, вытащенный вектор указывает в центр координат! Направление потеряно! Как вытащить данный вектор направления?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы немножко не с той стороны пытаетесь зайти, мне кажется.
Никто не вытаскивает из viewMatrix направление, наоборот хранят направление и позицию камеры и из них каждый кадр получают viewMatrix.

вот статья с хорошей теорией
http://www.gamedev.ru/code/articles/openglcamera

вот я по ней делал класс камеры:
https://github.com/Karavanych/DraziwGLesEngine/blob/master/src/draziw/gles/game/GLESCamera.java
сейчас он написан понятно, но не очень оптимально, я через пару дней доберусь до рабочего компа и перезалью проект, там будет более оптимально, но менее понятно и камера будет привязана к объекту (как в 3D-person)

краткое описание : http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=418429&view=findpost&p=42250559

Comment: Представим что у меня в определенный момент перед камерой появляется какой либо объект и находится впереди нее куда бы я ее не повернул, как бы вы решили такую задачу?

Comment: прибавляешь к координатам камеры вектор вперед камеры через коэффициент дистанции и все position+forward* distance

Comment: А как мне получить вектор направления камеры если я ее поворачивал с помощью rotare и направление было утеряно?

Comment: я и говорю что ты не с того края идешь, ты должен хранить вектора направлений(или матрицу направлений) и позицию камеры, поворачивать только направления, а потом получать viewMatrix из направлений и позиции. Почитай мануал на gamedev.

Comment: вот на эту картинку обрати внимание, она показывает как узнать направление. http://www.gamedev.ru/files/images/70105_1312799746_axis.png

Comment: Хорошо, вот у меня не выходит ни как получить вектор направления. подскажи какие именно элементы матрицы взять?

Comment: вот тут посмотри функцию поворота, там восстанавливаются направления из матрицы https://github.com/Karavanych/DraziwGLesEngine/blob/master/src/draziw/gles/game/GLESCamera.java

Comment: forward[0] = rotationMatrix[2];
forward[1] = rotationMatrix[6];
forward[2] = rotationMatrix[10]; Это? Если так то вы ошибаетесь, я точно так же пробовал брать эти значения, и при добавлении их к позиции, камера стремится в начало координат. пробовал и 8 9 10 и 2 6 10 и инвертировать и брать. Это не позиция куда направлена камера

Comment: Ак ты попробуй почитать всю теорию :) из viewMatrix конечно так просто направления не достать :) Но ты можешь взять мой проект с гитхаба скачать, запустить и убедится что камера работает :)

Comment: Ключ ко всему что ты хранишь отдельно матрицу поворота( или вектора направлений), отдельно координаты позиции камеры, и собираешь viewMatrix каждый кадр, потому что как только ты повернешь камеру вместе с координатами, естественно ты направление потеряешь, так как вращать можно только в координатах 0,0

Comment: Вот и я о том! Вы вытаскиваете вектор направления из матрицы поворота! Это работает! Но мне надо было из матрицы вида...

Comment: Да что вы за человек то такой. В 500ый раз повторяю не надо вытаскивать вектор направления из матрицы вида, а надо собирать матрицу вида из вектора направления.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28856/discussion-between-evgeny-karavashkin-and-cj1).